# Adding data to a table with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, azure-sql-database

I am working on a project in Visual Studio 2015 (**Universal**) . I want to do something very simple.

I want the user to write a Movie name, then click the "SAVE" button , so it can be added to my dbo.Movie table. 
 After that the Movie's name will be displayed above.

It is simple , but it seems that there aren't any tutorials for Visual Studio 2015 Universal Apps and System.Data.SqlClient does not exist .

I have to use SQL Azure anyway , since this is what the project asks for .

Answer (score 1):

You can't work with SQL Server database directly from UWP. UWP can be conected to SQL Server database with help of web service (WCF). Your application would be asking service for data and getting XML, JSON etc. as response.

In UWP you can have your own local SQLite database.

If you want to work with data that stored in Azure SQL database, I can recommend you Azure Mobile Apps (that service is like old Azure Mobile Services).

Here is short tutorial:
[Give your app a backend using Azure Mobile Apps](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Microsoft-Imagine/Give-your-app-a-backend-using-Azure-Mobile-Apps)
With Mobile Apps you can also easy synchronize you local SQLite database with cloud data.